# How to change the source anchor starting position in JsPlumb?

Tags: jsplumb

I'm developing an app using jsPlumb. Currently, if I create a shape, it puts the shape in the top left corner of the canvas. And If I connect from source to target point, it is working.

Now, I want to create the shape on the position where I right clicked and connect from source to target. I'm able to create the shape in the position where i right clicked.

But, if I drag from source to target, the source anchor is not starting from the source. Instead, it starts from the top left corner. In the screenshot below, I want to drag from 'Project' to 'No status' shape.

One more thing is, if I drag the 'Project' shape, endpoint is starting from source correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured the problem. Earlier, ,the if block (1) in the code was below the code (2). That's why even thought the shape moved to the new location, the starting location of the anchor didnt move. As soon as I move the if block(1) above (2), jsPlumb understands the shape's location as well as the anchor's starting point location.

So, if you are moving the shape, you should do it before you tell the shapes location to Jsplumb.

```
    if (!!shape.location) { ------------------------------------> 1)
        domEl.style.left = shape.location.left + 'px';
        domEl.style.top = shape.location.top + 'px';
    }

    this.jsPlumbInstance.draggable(domEl, {
        // to contain the shape within the canvas
        // containment: true
    });

    this.jsPlumbInstance.makeSource(domEl, { ----------------------2)
        filter: '.cp',
        anchor: ['AutoDefault'],
        connectorStyle: {
            stroke: '#181919',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            outlineStroke: 'transparent',
            outlineWidth: 4
        }
    });
```